# C++ thinks Templated Class' Constructor is a Function with an int Return Type

Tags: c++, class, templates

I keep getting the compiler error of

```
error: non-template type ‘const_iterator’ used as a template
In function ‘int const_iterator()’:
error: only constructors take base initializers
warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
```

However, I have const_iterator as a constructer.

Relevant code with other stuff removed:

.h file:

```
template <class T>
class test {

    public:

        // Forward declaration 
        class const_iterator;


        template <class Y>
        class const_iterator{
            public:
                template<class A> friend class test;

                // Default constructor
                const_iterator();
            private:
                Y* current;
        };
};
```

.cpp file:

```
// Default constructor
template <class T> 
test<T>::const_iterator<T>::const_iterator() : m_current(NULL){ }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you forward declare a template class you need to include the template part.  Doing that a forward declaration for `const_iterator` would look like

```
template <class Y>
class const_iterator;

// now you can use const_iterator as an incomplete type
```

That fixes the forward declaration but you also have an issue with the definition of the constructor.  Since `test` and `const_iterator` are both templates you need two separate templates when you define the constructor.  One for each of them.  That looks like

```
template <class T> // for test
template <class Y> // for const_iterator
test<T>::const_iterator<Y>::const_iterator() : current(nullptr){ }
```

You are also going to have another issue as you are separating your template class between a .h and .cpp files.  You cannot do that with templates.  For more on that subject see: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can't define your template methods in a .cpp file if you hope to actually use them, so just move the implementation to the header file and keep it simple.